# Why you need to substract from the stack pointer to allocate more memory?

Tags: assembly, x86

Why is `SUB esp, 4` for example is allocating 4 bytes on the stack and `ADD esp, 4` is deallocating? I mean, if it was the opposite it would be more understandable. I read about the stack and found out that in most cases it grows down towards the program's 0x00000000 address, but then, where is it starting from? Aren't the memory is dynamically allocated to the program from the OS when needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all some background information:

For many CPU types the direction of the stack is given by the CPU type. On the x86 for example certain operations automatically save data on the stack without using any software - for example hardware interrupts. There are instructions (like CALL or PUSH) that also save data on the stack. These operations modify the stack pointer so the direction of the stack is given.

However there are CPUs (TMS320F28xxx for example) where the direction of the stack is in the other direction. A value has to be added to the stack pointer to allocate memory on such CPUs. Other CPUs (like old ARM variants, MIPS, PowerPC or SPARC) do not have operations that explicitly address the stack so all stack operations must be done in software. On such CPUs the software could theoretically decide the direction of the stack.

Now the answer to your question:

On the x86 the stack grows downwards. This means that the addresses below ESP are overwritten when stack operations are used while the addresses above ESP are not touched.

When changing the value of ESP the position where memory is changed when using stack operations. If you subtract a value from ESP then the memory between the old ESP and the new ESP becomes protected from overwriting because the stack operations will overwrite memory below ESP. This means that this memory now is "yours". When adding a value to ESP then the memory between the old and the new ESP will be overwritten by stack operations. This means that that memory now is "free".

What happens when ESP reaches 0x00000000?

In fact, there is only a certain range where stack may be located. Maybe in the range 0x40001000 to 0x40002000. This range depends on the operating system and the program running. If ESP is outside this range you'll get an error. On x86 CPUs in protected mode there will be an exception; on microcontrollers (the register name is not "ESP" on such devices) you'll overwrite memory that is not reserved for the stack so maybe you'll overwrite global variables or so...

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it all depends on the OS decision? I've worked with PIC microcontrollers for example and I know there isn't "something" to protect the stack from growing and overwriting the the rest of the program memory, but on Windows for example, the OS manages all this memory allocations and allocate stack for every application and checks that it didn't overstep it's bounds? Also, I would like to ask, in the example you given above, the addresses are "virtual addresses" that assigned to the program? The program exceuting on some sort of a sandbox?